# How can I find this info in the console?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there a way to know in the console when you die and when a round starts or ends? Can I get info for shots fired, hit, and headshots on a single round?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course you can. There are certain keyword that appear in the console when you shoot/kill/hit and enemy player. For this, you can use filters in the console. [Here](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=221277004) is a guide for it.

**Where to Enter Commands:**
`config/autoexec/valve.rc` or console

**Commands:**

```
developer "1"
con_filter_text "Damage"
con_filter_text_out "Player:"
con_filter_enable "2"
```

**To create a bind for quick access:**

```
bind "Key" "displaydamage"

//Displaydamage - Switch Script by 3st
alias displaydamage "displaydamage_off"
alias displaydamage_on "con_filter_text Damage; con_filter_text_out Player:; con_filter_enable 2; developer 1; alias displaydamage displaydamage_off"
alias displaydamage_off "con_filter_enable 0; developer 0; clear; alias displaydamage displaydamage_on"
```

Just copy it into your *.cfg and replace "Key" with a key of your choice.

> If you do not have an autoexec.cfg or valve.rc or any other way to
>   execute scripts in game don't panic. You have two choices: If you do
>   not want to use the switch script you can go the easy way and simply
>   enter "The Commands" from above into your console in game.
>
> If you want to use the script you will have to create an autoexec.cfg.
>
> **Step 1:** Go to your Windows desktop, click your right mouse button and
>   create a new text file.
>
> **Step 2:** Open it and copy my script from above into it. Be sure to
>   replace "Key" with a key of your choice. I myself use "KP_HOME" - it's
>   the 7 on the keyboard's numpad.
>
> **Step 3:** Write "host_writeconfig" in the last row of your text file.

Comment: While this does answer the question you may want to summarize a the information in the link since the link may go down making this answer not helpful anymore.